# How do I eliminate elements in the same position in two lists but just filtering one list?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have two lists i.e.:

```
a = [0.0 , 30.1, 0.0, 10.1]
b = [1000, 9830, 100, 1023]
```

I want to remove from list "a" the elements equals to 0.0 and remove the elements from list "b" which are in the same position of the elements 0.0 in the list "a".
I know I can do this saving the index of 0.0 elements in a list, and then delete from the list b.  Is there something more efficient? Because I want to apply the method in very large datasets.
Thanks

Comment: Do the 2 lists are guaranteed to have the same length? If not, you might want to take it into consideration. Also, the list implementation matters a lot when you are removing elements - an array-backed list will need a shift operation while a linked list won't. In any case, a way would be iterating on both lists at once (from end towards beginning might be easier) and removing elements from B as you find `0.0` on A.

Comment: Yes, both lists always will have the same length.

Comment: Your solutions sounds good. I will try this. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using NumPy is of the most efficient ways. It is very easy doing so by NumPy indexing if you can use this library, without needing loops and much more faster. We need to convert them to arrays and reconvert them to list by `.tolist()` if needed:

```
a = np.array(a)
b = np.array(b)

a_ = a[a == 0]
# [0. 0.]
b_ = b[a != 0]
# [9830 1023]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```python
a = [0.0 , 30.1, 0.0, 10.1]
b = [1000, 9830, 100, 1023]
#####################################################
assert(len(a) == len(b))
b = [b[index] if value != 0 else "" for index, value in enumerate(a)]
b = list(filter(lambda x: x != "", b))
#####################################################
print(b) # prints [9830, 1023]
```